# Is there a quick way to override the UI widget for a single property in an addon?

Tags: python, interface, operator

I'm experimenting with an addon that has multiple properties.  I want one of them to be a drop-down that lets you pick from the list of armatures.

I have found example code where you can override the `draw()` method of the operator:

```
class ParentGearsToActive(bpy.types.Operator):
    """connect selected gears to active gear and ensure that they mesh correctly"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.parent_gears_to_active"
    bl_label = "Parent Selected Gears To Active Gear"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    phase_degrees = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="phase", default=0, min=0, max=1)
    offset = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="axial offset", default=0)
    master_rotor = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Master rotor", default="")
    armature = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Armature", default="")

    def draw(self, ctx):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Phase:")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self, "phase_degrees", text="")

        layout.label("Axial offset:")
        layout.prop(self, "offset", text="")

        # armatures = { "objects" : [ o for o in ctx.scene.objects if hasattr(o.data, "bones")]}
        # that bit doesn't work how I want, continue stupidly
        armatures = ctx.scene

        layout.label("Armature:")
        layout.prop_search(self, "armature", armatures, "objects", text="")
        layout.label("Master rotor:")
        layout.prop_search(self, "master_rotor", armatures, "objects", text="")
```

However, when I consider applying this to another operator which has around 12 properties, I begin to cringe.  Am I overlooking a better way to define the property that would let me avoid overriding the `draw()` method?